# PWA don't add to home

Tags: manifest, progressive-web-apps, homescreen

I'm developing a PWA application and the "add to home" function isn't working. The Service Worker seems to be fine, just like the manifest.

This is PWA: https://tanafonte.com.br/app/

Answer (score 1):

Add [lighthouse](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lighthouse/blipmdconlkpinefehnmjammfjpmpbjk?hl=en) to your browser and it will tell you what it thinks is wrong. Personally I think it is far too obtuse and opinionated but there you go.

Comment: I had it installed, but I could not understand the problem through it.

Answer (score 0):

That's the lighthouse error I get for your PWA: "Failures: Service worker does not successfully serve the manifest's start_url, Timed out waiting for fetched start_url."

At your manifest.json you set the property start_url to /app which results into https://tanafonte.com.br/app
This URL is redirected with 301 to https://tanafonte.com.br/app/

Maybe that's the problem. I would try to set the start_url to /app/